# User-defined type in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, user-defined

Can I define a data type named HundredBytes in Haskell such that a value of TwoBytes will always have 100 bytes?

Thanks!

Comment: HundredBytes, TwoBytes ... are they related to each other?

Comment: please update your question, how these 2 classes related to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Haskell has no concept of byte, which is generally a good thing—it's almost always more useful to think about the width of a number in bits than in bytes, especially since implementations are allowed to use tag bits. If you want something with 100 `Word8` values, you can do this:

```
data Two a = Two a a
data Five a = Five a a a a a
newtype Hundred = Hundred (Five (Five (Two (Two Word8))))
```